# Asyncio blocks the main event loop when the task is cancelled

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, blocking, event-loop

**Problem:**

Python version: 3.7

We have one API which makes a call to the database. 
In order for the DB call to not block the event loop, we run the task in the background using asyncio.
We get a large number of requests and we don't want other calls to be blocked while processing current request 
The request timeout for the incoming request is 60 seconds. 
It works fine in most of the cases. But the main thread is not responsive for few seconds when one of the task running in a thread is canceled.

for example, the below is a function in the controller. This calls the database. I have simplified it with time.sleep.

**Code:**

```
 async def __transform(self, request: web.Request):
    loop_example = LoopExample(request['parameters'])
    result = await loop_example.run_loop()            
    return response

 class LoopExample:
     __loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

     def __init__(self, parameters):
         self.parameters = user_context.logger

    async def run_loop(self):
        try:
           print(f"main threadId: {threading.get_ident()}")
           return await self.__loop.run_in_executor(None, self.wait)
        except Exception as e:
           self.logger.exception(e)
           print(f"exception threadid(goes back to main thread): {threading.get_ident()}")

    //the below method is the blocking call. 
    def wait(self):
        print(f"blocking loop threadId: {threading.get_ident()}")
        time.sleep(60)
```

**Notes:**

I have tested with sending multiple requests at the same time. I can see multiple thread IDs (one for each request) getting printed and obviously they are not blocking the main event loop. But when one of the task running in a thread is canceled (because when the input request's HTTP timeout, I get a CancelledError like this

`"""in run_loop\n    return await self.__loop.run_in_executor(None, self.wait)\nconcurrent.futures._base.CancelledError"} )"""`,

when this happens, the service is not responsive for few seconds. After a few seconds (~8 seconds), it is back to normal. So in the 8 seconds, other requests which hit the endpoint get a 502 (Gateway timeout error). 
Also from the docs https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html, looks like python uses ThreadPoolExecutor as Default. 
I tried explicitly specifying the ThreadPoolExecutor and it's the same behavior.  Can someone help me in identifying what is wrong here? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "But when one of the thread is canceled ..." part? It's confusing because threads can't be canceled, asyncio tasks can. Also, regarding "because when the input request's HTTP timeout, I get a CancelledError" - how does the timeout occur, exactly? Is it an external event, the peer timing out, or a call to `asyncio.wait_for` or other asyncio API that cancels the task?

Comment: @user4815162342  It is a task running in a thread which is canceled and that is the only task running in the thread(updated the question above).  for your second question, it is the peer timing out. the request goes via nginx and nginx tears down it's connection to the server. Thanks for your time.

Comment: *It is a task running in a thread which is canceled* - What is cancelled, the thread or the task? And how is it cancelled, can you show the code that cancels it?

Comment: A task is Canceled. I am not sure how I can show that part of the code which initiates the cancellation. I just get a CancelledError when that happens. I think the code for cancelling the task comes from aiohttp. aiohttp interrupts the request which results in task cancellation.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now - your code is waiting in `run_in_executor`, aiohttp cancels the whole task due to a timeout deadline being overstepped, and you get `CancelledError`. But the service then stops for several seconds. I would try to debug this by using `strace -f -o tracefile` on the whole process, and examining `tracefile` to find out what the process is doing during those 8 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that sometime today and get back to you. apart from that, do you see anything which is obvious that I am missing?

Comment: Unfortunately not - your usage of asyncio seems legit. It would help if you could build a _runnable_ example that reproduces the issue - like you have above, using `time.time()` to emulate the blocking code, but that includes aiohttp server setup.